# Three.js - transparency issue in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, transparency

I have an issue to visualise a 3D object using three.js when other transparent objects cover it. When there are transparent objects next to a 3D object (the green object in the left image), some parts of the 3D object are not visualised correctly. However, when you hide those neighbor objects from the scene, it is visualised correctly (the green object in the right image).

How can I have vertical walls visible similar to the right image below without hiding neighbor transparent objects?

Thanks.

[image: The left image shows vertical walls are not appeared correctly. Right image shows vertical walls correctly!]

Comment: this might help: `renderer.sortObjects = false;`

Comment: Please write the answer so others can use it. (and mark it as answered)